# How to create SageMaker Studio environment from CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I can create SageMaker Notebook instance from `aws sagemaker create-notebook-instance --notebook-instance-name test-123`
but I can't find a similiar CLI command to create a **"SageMaker Studio"** instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[SageMaker Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio.html) is a web-based IDE for machine learning, with multiple components. At its core, Studio consists of a Domain and a list of user profiles. Each user profile can contain multiple "apps" which can host notebook instances, among other features.
See [Onboard to Amazon SageMaker Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-studio-onboard.html) for details. Each of these can be created through the CLI, such as -

- [create-domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-domain.html)
- [create-user-profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-user-profile.html)
- [create-app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-app.html)